# Range.Find unable to find Timestamp

Tags: excel, vba

I think I've tried literally everything including converting the Timestamp back into date using `CDate`
The code is a test I'm running to get the `Range.Find` to work in the first place. The file in which i look up the time stamp is formatted as special dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm for example **01.01.2019  00:00** whereas in the formula bar it is **01.01.2019  00:00:00**

EDIT : Removed the quotes around sDate, a copy and paste mistake

```
Sub trial()
Dim r As Range
Dim sDate As String
Dim find As Range
Dim col As Long


Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_WIND").Range("d11")

col = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("INPUT_WIND").Range("d11").Column

sDate = Format(r.Offset(, -col + 2), "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm")

Debug.Print sDate
Set find = Workbooks("FINO raw-010119-310819").Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").find(sDate, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)

If Not find Is Nothing Then

Debug.Print find.Offset(, 1)

Else

MsgBox "nicht gefunden"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.find(sDate, LookIn:=xlValues ...`

Comment: Remove the quotes from the find around `sDate` otherwise it is tryin to find the anctual word `sDate` and not the value stored in the variable

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah, that was a copy paste mistake, it doesn't work either way

Comment: If the dates in the worksheet are real dates, look for the underlying number which will be a `Double`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes they are real dates, how do i match the underlying number with the actual dates i.e in date format in the other range?

Comment: The format is irrelevant. Do something like `Range.Find(What:=CDbl(ur_real_date)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this fix

```
Sub trial()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim find As Range
    Dim col As Long


    Set r = Range("d11")

    col = Range("d11").Column

    sDate = r.Offset(, -col + 2)

    Debug.Print sDate
    Set find = Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").find(CDate(sDate), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not find Is Nothing Then

        Debug.Print find.Offset(, 1)

    Else

        MsgBox "nicht gefunden"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I did, again it was unable to find the date. Funnily, it worked previously on a couple of occasions

Comment: Debug the code and look at the value of  `sdate`. Also look at the value of what you expect to find. Is there a difference?

Comment: my sdate is 01.02.2019 01:10:00 and i want it to find 01.02.2019 01:10

Comment: when l ctrl+F after running the code, the date in the right format is already in the search box and when i manually hit Find, it manages to find the date.

Comment: remember that date/time are stored as doubles, and there are a lot of decimal places between `01.02.2019 01:10:00` and `01.02.2019 01:10:59`  Trying to use date/time and find are tricky as just because two times show `01.02.2019 01:10` they may not actually be the same number down to 15 sig digits. @neutronhammer

Comment: true, but if i were to convert it to a string, it ought to work shouldn't it ? what would you suggest? a vlookup? i think i'll give it a go